# List only three element n my homepage in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```html
{% for post in BusinessPost %}
<ul>
    <li>{{ post.title}} -- {{post.author}} -- {{post.source_date}} </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

this is my code to get all the element of my model into listView page but i only want to get the first 3 element of this list. Can anyone help

Comment: Share your `ListView`.

Comment: Look up Python documentation for _indexing_ into a `list` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the queryset with:

```
class BusinessPostListView(ListView):
    #                  obtain the first 3 ↓
    queryset = BusinessPost.objects.all()[:3]

    # …
```

Comment: <h1>Post</h1>


<ul>
    {% for post in BusinessPost.objects.all()[:3] %}

    <li>{{ post.title}} -- {{post.author}} -- {{post.source_date}} </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}

Comment: @DilnesahuGETACEW: that will not work. Django's template language deliberately does not allow method calls and subscripting, to avoid people writing such things (business logic) in the template.

Comment: its in django template i need this

Comment: @DilnesahuGETACEW: well that would be horrible code design. Templates are *not* for business logic, templates should focus on *rendering* logic.

Comment: how can i do it then

Comment: @DilnesahuGETACEW Put it in your `views.py!`!!